# What is the difference between IlleagalStateException and NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I would like to throw an error in the following code

```
if (!this.isAttached(object.getElementById(Name))) 
{
     throw new NoSuchElementException(Name);
}
this.clickElement(object.getElementById(Name));
```

Which is the most appropriate exception to throw: `NoSuchElementException` or `IllegalStateException`

Comment: Either way is fine. Just make sure your exceptions are consistent throughout your application.

Comment: Is it an illegal state if the object is not attached? Is there no element when the object is not attached? You're the only one who could know the answer to the former and the latter sounds obviously false (but it really depends on what the rest of your code looks like). This is definitely [primarily opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), there's no objective "right" answer.

Comment: There is no good or wrong in this case, judging on the context you have provided. You can ask yourself if you want to use exceptions at all. If so, the next question to ask if you want to use unchecked or checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You will understand more from documentation :

> [**NoSuchElementException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)
>   Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that
>   there are no more elements in the enumeration.
>
> [**IllegalStateException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) Signals that a method has been invoked at an
>   illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or
>   Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested
>   operation.

In your cases it doesn't matter what exception you will throw `NoSuchElementException` or `IllegalStateException` or even `Exception`, because it throw just a message and not the real exception.

If you read about the constructor of any exception you can understand :

> `public AnyException(String s)`
>
> Constructs an AnyException with the specified detail message.
>   **A detail message is a String that describes this particular exception**.

Comment: `Exception` is a checked exception, which will require him to declare `Exception` in his method or constructor header and to try-catch everywhere the method is being used. `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException` are unchecked, and are not required to declare on the method or constructor header. So I wouldn't go with `Exception`.

Comment: maybe @Velth for purpose i don't mention any thing what is the best way it should be to use, i just clarify some unclear things that's all

Comment: I was under the impression you hinted for "it does't matter what exception you use, you can even throw Exception", which I think is not true ;-). I might have misunderstood.